# Does a difference of tense count as a difference of meaning in a minimal pair?

Tags: tense, minimal-pairs

**Does a difference in tense count as a difference in meaning in a minimal pair?**

Here's a made up example to illustrate my question:

If we know that:

- [wuga] means "read"
- [wugi] means "reading"

Can we say that [wuga] and [wugi] are a minimal pair and that [a] and [i] contrast?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. A minimal pair is meant to differ in one phoneme, to demonstrate that a speaker of the language can distinguish between the two words, and therefore that the contrast is phonemic. Since the difference between the words is on the level of phonology, it doesn't matter whether the difference in meaning is grammatical or lexical.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the issue is not as clear as the preceding answer states.
One issue here is morpheme-boundary.
It's not good policy to look for minimal pairs that involve morpheme boundaries. For example, drink drank drunk is ok because there is no boundary involved here, but there is the well-known case of Scottish English where vowel length normally does not exist, but some long vowels actually exist in words like Preterite laid < lay+ed. In other words, your pair wugi / wuga is not a fully satisfactory minimal pair. It might involve interferences caused by morpheme boundaries. So I would recommend to look for another minimal pair that does not involve that kind of issues.

Comment: Why would differences in morphological structure be relevant to deciding if two words form a minimal pair? The minimal pair test only refers to the phonetic segments in the words.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this argument, but, for example, in English consonant length is generally not considered phonemic, yet if you take a word boundary, or even a morpheme boundary, you can have the same consonant twice, which results, for instance, in *unaimed* [ʌn'eɪmd] vs *unnamed* [ʌn'neɪmd], with a (potential, at least) geminate. Does this mean the analysis positing that consonant length is not phonemic in English is wrong, or does it mean that minimal pairs shouldn't be constructed across morpheme boundaries?

Comment: @user6726 *Rosa's* vs. *roses*. This famous pair is not truly a minimal pair ([Flemming & Johnson 2007](http://web.mit.edu/~flemming/www/paper/rosasroses.pdf)). If English orthography marked the boundary between the stem and the plural suffix nobody would have even considered that possibility. Morphological structure is absolutely relevant because it shapes the definition of a word.

Comment: To follow Nardog, the issue is that defining what a "word" is not as clear as one may hope. So the best minimal pairs are those involving unanalyzable morphemes.

Comment: @Nardog I've read the paper but it doesn't seem to say that *Rosa's* vs *roses* is *not* a minimal pair; I even find hints they consider it one, like "[...] a sequence of 25 minimal pairs (roses–Rosa’s, [...])". Anyway, while I think I see why you say they're not, and I've argued for that too earlier... if hypothetically *Rosa's* and *roses* were the *only* examples of [ɨ] vs [ə], would it be fair to say that /ɨ/ and /ə/ aren't separate phonemes in English because there is no minimal pair? I'd still say the utterances [ɹoʊzɨz] vs [ɹoʊzəz] show a meaningful distinction, indicating phonemicity.

Comment: How do we know that *i*/*a* in *wugi*/*wuga* is not part of the stem, like in *drink*/*drank*?

Comment: @LjL It is a minimal pair only in the sense that *a tease* vs. *at ease* is. It doesn't entail a change in the phonemic inventory.

Comment: @Nardog but the paper claims (and shows) that *Rosa's* and *roses* are pronounced differently. If that difference is not phonemic, I don't think you've shown why, and that paper doesn't seem to claim that (although at this point, I've partly forgotten what the paper said).

Comment: @LjL p. 94: "the minimal contrast between barred-i and schwa in pairs like *roses–Rosa's* can only arise because of the difference in morphological structure between the two words: in *roses* the stem boundary precedes the reduced vowel, [[ɹoʊz]ɨz], while in *Rosa's* it follows it, [[ɹoʊzə]z]. This contrast does not arise in other contexts, such as within monomorphemic words." If we don't take morphological structures into consideration, [tʰ] [t] [ɾ] etc. must become separate phonemes because of the pairs like *a tease* vs. *at ease*. *Rosa's* vs. *roses* is no different.

Comment: @LjL Of course, in an accent without the weak vowel merger (i.e. *abbot* and *rabbit* don't rhyme), *roses* and *Rosa's* are phonemicized differently, btw.